# In JavaScript ES6, iterable[Symbol.iterator] is called with `this` bound to iterable, but Mozilla and ES6 specs both didn't mention it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, iterable

Currently, both the [Mozilla specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) and the [ES6 specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-iterable-interface) mentioned that for an iterable `obj`, the following meaning:

> `obj[Symbol.iterator]` should refer to a zero-argument function, such that when called, should return an object that conforms to the iterator protocol

But none of them them mentioned that this function is actually invoked on `obj` itself.

It may be important because there is such usage that I just saw:

```js
const aClass = {
  teacher: "Mary",
  students: ["Peter", "Michael"],
  location: "Room 123, Building One",
  
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
    yield this.teacher;
    for (const student of this.students) {
      yield student;
    }
  }
};

for (const member of aClass) console.log(member);

console.log([...aClass]);
```

Note that the teacher and both students were printed.

So this `[Symbol.iterator]` protocol is like: giving the user of this object a way to iterate over me, in a way that I specify.

So the spec on Mozilla and ES6 really should mention that this function is invoked on the iterable, or with `this` bound to the iterable?

(or maybe the ES6 implementation specs mentioned it... but I thought interface should tell everything about how it is used and shouldn't require the users to read the implementation as well).

Comment: Nope this is not "bound". You can .bind() that function to an other object, and the this value will be preserved. That's just a method, like any function set as a property of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically `.call` a `[Symbol.iterator]` with whichever `this` value you want:

```js
const aClass = {
  teacher: "Mary",
  students: ["Peter", "Michael"],
  location: "Room 123, Building One",
  
  [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
    yield this.teacher;
    for (const student of this.students) {
      yield student;
    }
  }
};

const iterator = aClass[Symbol.iterator].call({ foo: null });
console.log(iterator.next());
console.log(iterator.next());
```

but for this case, you're invoking the iterator via

```
console.log([...aClass]);
```

which performs (among other things) the steps described in [ArrayAccumulation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation):

```
SpreadElement : ... AssignmentExpression

1. Let spreadRef be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
2. Let spreadObj be GetValue(spreadRef).
3. Let iterator be GetIterator(spreadObj).
4. ReturnIfAbrupt(iterator).
5. Repeat (iterate over iterator, assign properties to the array being created)
```

Take a look at [`GetIterator`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getiterator):

```
  a. Let method be GetMethod(obj, @@iterator).
  ...
3. Let iterator be Call(method,obj).
```

Where `obj` is the first argument passed (which, for `ArrayAccumulation`, is the `spreadObj`).

What `Call` does is it invokes the function passed as the first argument with a calling context (a `this`) of the second argument.

So `[...aClass]` invokes `aClass[Symbol.iterator]` with a calling context of `aClass`.

The `for..of` loop gets the iterator from [Runtime Semantics: ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind), which does, in this case:

```
a. Assert: iterationKind is iterate.
b. Return GetIterator(exprValue).
```

Resulting in the same sort of thing as `[...aClass]` (the iterator on `aClass` gets called with a calling context of `aClass`)

Comment: isn't this `Call(method,obj)` similar to `fn.call(obj)`? (or `apply`, or `bind`, or just setting `obj` and `fn` to something and invoking by `obj.fn()`)... yeah I think it should be mentioned in the specs, rather than in the implementation. But I just read Mozilla's description carefully. It mentioned "method"... I guess in a way suggesting it is a method invoked on the object... but you kind of have to read it and make the inference.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty similar, though it's abstract (it exists in the specification to show how things should work, but doesn't necessarily exist in an actual implementation's code). MDN shows *examples* of how an iterator of an object uses `this` inside to refer to the object, but it never explicitly says that that's the way things work. But MDN isn't meant to be *entirely comprehensive*, that's what the official specification is for. The official specification *should* be comprehensive, and it looks to be. Still, MDN's a wiki, anyone can edit it

Comment: I think really the ES6 specs should mention it is a function invoked on the iterable, without users looking at how it is implemented. It is especially true on the ES6 specs as it uses the word "function" instead of "method".

Comment: The "how it is implemented" part *is* an official and necessary part of the specification. If the place where the method retrieval mechanism was described was outside of `GetIterator`, farther up the chain, there'd be loss of generality *and* more repetitive descriptions. (eg, if it was described at `ArrayAccumulation`, and also separately described in `ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation`, that's result in a more repetitive spec. Best for code (and descriptions) to be as [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) as possible)

Comment: In many specs, such as Ruby, Python, C, Lisp... they only specify the behaviors and not how it is implemented. Ruby showed how it was implemented on some website but it was a little bit cryptic, and users can usually ignore it altogether. JavaScript is one exception. I guess it is even true for machine code: just tell me it will be finished in one clock cycle and I don't care how it is implemented. I guess sometimes it matters, that it is implemented in such a way so if you use this method, be ready the range 0 to n is made into an array so a lot of memory can be used

Comment: Everything described in the specification *is* essentially just describing what the observable behaviors should be. Engines do not have to implement all of the abstract methods and such that are described in the specification, for example - they just have to operate such that the output produced *would be the same* as if, given the input, someone went through the spec step-by-step. The specification is intended to give readers a human-understandable idea of how everything is meant to fit together, but it's not instructions for building an interpreter.

Comment: I don't quite get how what you said is related to "we should not only read ES6 specs and interface, but how ES6 is implemented step by step". The idea of black box is, don't tell me what is inside. Just tell me what it does. And if there is a better way to implement it some day, go ahead and do it, the users don't have to care. But tell me about, whether I can concat the same array to itself, whether it is ok. One of the biggest thing in SIPC is that it is a black box or abstraction. And how it is implemented shouldn't matter. But I guess not everybody believe in this idea.

Comment: If you're trying to figure out exactly why Y behavior happens given X input, a black box is not helpful at all - the specification exists *so that* there can be concrete answers to questions like yours. Without all the complicated steps in the spec, there'd be no standard, and with no standard, cross-browser, cross-platform JS would be impossible

Comment: if you have Ruby or Python, it runs on a PC, or Mac, or Linux the same way. Python users don't say, "let me see how string concatenation is implemented".